# Plural form after zero

Tags: grammatical-number, determiners

I came across this sentence:

> I have zero friends

Why the plurality? Seems pretty counterintuitive to me. Is there a general grammar rule behind it?

Comment: Related, but not identical question with a good answer that covers this: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/7817/singular-or-plural-for-seconds/7825#7825

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Singular is only used with **one** or **1** or words that mean exactly one, like **single**.

So, if you rephrase as:

> I don't have a single *friend*.

It's singular.

But zero, though it's not greater than one, it's not one, either, so you use the plural form.

Also, as Adam said in the comments, numbers that are equivalent to 1 like **1.0** or **e<sup>(2π*i* )</sup>**  would still get the plural form.

Comment: And it must be "one," "a," or "1," not just something equal to one.  _I have 1 friend.  I have 1.0 friends.  I have e^(2 pi i) friends._