# How to pronounce decimals?

Tags: pronunciation, mathematics, reading-aloud

Something like:

```
0.1
0.23
0.999
```

How to pronounce them correctly in English?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Singular or plural for seconds](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/7817/singular-or-plural-for-seconds)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. That question is specifically about singular vs plural, where this is about pronunciation in general.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> 0.1

*"zero-point-one"*

> 0.23

*"zero-point-two-three"*

> 0.999

*"zero-point-nine-nine-nine"*

*"point"* = the decimal point

Comment: I agree, but I think it's worth noting that you can leave the zero out. "point-five" is still correct for 0.5. 1.5 should be "one-point-five" but it's different with a zero.